# a heap-buffer-overflow with my c code when i use recursion to solve leetcode task 22

Tags: c, gcc, malloc, heap-memory, strcpy

When i run my c code my solution is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LEN 1000

int isValid(char* curStr) {
    char* ptr = curStr;
    int leftCount = 0;
    while (*ptr != '\0') {
        if (*ptr == '(') {
            leftCount++;
        } else {  // *ptr == ')'
            leftCount--;
        }
        if (leftCount < 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        ptr++;
    }
    return leftCount == 0;
}

void generateParenthesisRecursive(char* curStr, int curStrLen, int n, int* returnSize, char** res) {
    // exit condition of recursive
    if (curStrLen == 2 * n) {
        if (isValid(curStr)) {
            res[(*returnSize)] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (curStrLen + 1));
            strcpy(res[(*returnSize)], curStr);
            (*returnSize)++;
        }
        return;
    }
    // iterate recursively
    char* curStrNewLeft = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (curStrLen + 2));
    char* curStrNewRight = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (curStrLen + 2));
    strcat(curStrNewLeft, curStr);
    strcat(curStrNewLeft, "(");
    strcat(curStrNewRight, curStr);
    strcat(curStrNewRight, ")");

    generateParenthesisRecursive(curStrNewLeft, curStrLen + 1, n, returnSize, res);
    generateParenthesisRecursive(curStrNewRight, curStrLen + 1, n, returnSize, res);
}

char ** generateParenthesisV2(int n, int* returnSize){
    // initialize *returnSize to zero
    *returnSize = 0;
    // create final return result
    char** res = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *) * MAX_LEN);
    char* curStr = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 1);
    curStr[0] = '\0';
    generateParenthesisRecursive(curStr, 0, n, returnSize, res);
    return res;
}
```

Then i execute gcc build command and run the binary file

```
gcc -fsanitize=address -o ${OUTPUT_BUILD_FILE_PATH} ${MAIN_FILE_PATH}
./${MAIN_FILE_PATH}
```

I got the heap-buffer-overflow information as following:

```
GenerateParentheses_Task22-main(7574,0x7ff84ea6f640) malloc: nano zone abandoned due to inability to reserve vm space.
=================================================================
==7574==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x6020000000d2 at pc 0x0001064c1e77 bp 0x7ff7b9e17dc0 sp 0x7ff7b9e17568
WRITE of size 1 at 0x6020000000d2 thread T0
    #0 0x1064c1e76 in wrap_strcat+0x426 (libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64h+0x42e76) (BuildId: 756bb7515781379f84412f22c4274ffd2400000010000000000a0a0000030d00)
    #1 0x1060e9bb3 in generateParenthesisRecursive+0x223 (GenerateParentheses_Task22-main:x86_64+0x100002bb3) (BuildId: f1d1bd488ca8367a9d17ae1d6b27c6c732000000200000000100000000000d00)
    #2 0x1060e9cfd in generateParenthesisV2+0xdd (GenerateParentheses_Task22-main:x86_64+0x100002cfd) (BuildId: f1d1bd488ca8367a9d17ae1d6b27c6c732000000200000000100000000000d00)
    #3 0x1060ea9aa in main+0x7a (GenerateParentheses_Task22-main:x86_64+0x1000039aa) (BuildId: f1d1bd488ca8367a9d17ae1d6b27c6c732000000200000000100000000000d00)
    #4 0x7ff80b03941e in start+0x76e (dyld:x86_64+0xfffffffffff6e41e) (BuildId: 9e98a840a3ac31c1ab97829af9bd686432000000200000000100000000040d00)

0x6020000000d2 is located 0 bytes to the right of 2-byte region [0x6020000000d0,0x6020000000d2)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x1064c7da0 in wrap_malloc+0xa0 (libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64h+0x48da0) (BuildId: 756bb7515781379f84412f22c4274ffd2400000010000000000a0a0000030d00)
    #1 0x1060e9b8c in generateParenthesisRecursive+0x1fc (GenerateParentheses_Task22-main:x86_64+0x100002b8c) (BuildId: f1d1bd488ca8367a9d17ae1d6b27c6c732000000200000000100000000000d00)
    #2 0x1060e9cfd in generateParenthesisV2+0xdd (GenerateParentheses_Task22-main:x86_64+0x100002cfd) (BuildId: f1d1bd488ca8367a9d17ae1d6b27c6c732000000200000000100000000000d00)
    #3 0x1060ea9aa in main+0x7a (GenerateParentheses_Task22-main:x86_64+0x1000039aa) (BuildId: f1d1bd488ca8367a9d17ae1d6b27c6c732000000200000000100000000000d00)
    #4 0x7ff80b03941e in start+0x76e (dyld:x86_64+0xfffffffffff6e41e) (BuildId: 9e98a840a3ac31c1ab97829af9bd686432000000200000000100000000040d00)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow (libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64h+0x42e76) (BuildId: 756bb7515781379f84412f22c4274ffd2400000010000000000a0a0000030d00) in wrap_strcat+0x426
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x1c03ffffffc0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1c03ffffffd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1c03ffffffe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1c03fffffff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1c0400000000: fa fa fd fd fa fa 00 00 fa fa 00 00 fa fa 00 06
=>0x1c0400000010: fa fa 00 00 fa fa 01 fa fa fa[02]fa fa fa 02 fa
  0x1c0400000020: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x1c0400000030: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x1c0400000040: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x1c0400000050: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x1c0400000060: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
==7574==ABORTING
[1]    7574 abort      ./DynamicProgramming/22-Generate_Parentheses/C/GenerateParentheses_Task22-mai
```

Can anyone help me fix this problem?
About 1 hours i had spent on figuring this out, but it didn't work.
Btw, what methods can i use to debug to locate heap-buffer-overflow more efficiently?

-------------------- split line ---------------------

Thanks for suggestions from @Weather Vane, @Whozcry and @Jim Morrison, it's better to initialize the block allocated by malloc, so i optimized my code in these changes:

1. directly pass empty string "" and curStrLen(0) to recursive function at the beginning
2. replace calloc with malloc on initialization
3. free each curStr when curStrLen is more than zero (when curStrLen equals to zero, the initial empty string cannot be free because it is not allocated by malloc)
4. use `strcpy(curStrNewLeft, curStr)` instead of `strcat(curStrNewLeft, curStr)`

The updated code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LEN 1000

int isValid(char* curStr) {
    char* ptr = curStr;
    int leftCount = 0;
    while (*ptr != '\0') {
        if (*ptr == '(') {
            leftCount++;
        } else {  // *ptr == ')'
            leftCount--;
        }
        if (leftCount < 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        ptr++;
    }
    return leftCount == 0;
}

void generateParenthesisRecursive(char* curStr, int curStrLen, int n, int* returnSize, char** res) {
    // exit condition of recursive
    if (curStrLen == 2 * n) {
        if (isValid(curStr)) {
            res[(*returnSize)] = (char *) calloc(curStrLen + 1, sizeof(char));
            strcpy(res[(*returnSize)], curStr);
            (*returnSize)++;
        }
        return;
    }
    // iterate recursively
    char* curStrNewLeft = (char *) calloc(curStrLen + 2, sizeof(char));
    strcpy(curStrNewLeft, curStr);
    strcat(curStrNewLeft, "(");

    char* curStrNewRight = (char *) calloc(curStrLen + 2, sizeof(char));
    strcpy(curStrNewRight, curStr);
    strcat(curStrNewRight, ")");

    if (curStrLen > 0) {
        free(curStr);
    }
    generateParenthesisRecursive(curStrNewLeft, curStrLen + 1, n, returnSize, res);
    generateParenthesisRecursive(curStrNewRight, curStrLen + 1, n, returnSize, res);
}

char ** generateParenthesisV2(int n, int* returnSize){
    // initialize *returnSize to zero
    *returnSize = 0;
    // create final return result
    char** res = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *) * MAX_LEN);
    generateParenthesisRecursive("", 0, n, returnSize, res);
    return res;
}
```

Everything runs ok on my mac with clion, but when i build it to binary file with gcc to run, i still got the heap-buffer-overflow problem, then i use valgrind that @Whozcry recommended to me:
`valgrind --leak-check=full ./GenerateParentheses_Task22-main`
the output is:

```
==39646== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==39646== Copyright (C) 2002-2022, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==39646== Using Valgrind-3.22.0.GIT-lbmacos and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==39646== Command: ./GenerateParentheses_Task22-main
==39646== 
==39646== Syscall param map_with_linking_np(link_info) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==39646==    at 0x10007BE32: __map_with_linking_np (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==39646==    by 0x10002BE4D: dyld4::setUpPageInLinkingRegions(dyld4::RuntimeState&, dyld4::Loader const*, unsigned long, unsigned short, unsigned short, bool, dyld3::Array<dyld4::PageInLinkingRange> const&, dyld3::Array<void const*> const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==39646==    by 0x10002B820: invocation function for block in dyld4::Loader::setUpPageInLinking(Diagnostics&, dyld4::RuntimeState&, unsigned long, unsigned long long, dyld3::Array<void const*> const&) const (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==39646==    by 0x10002B5A4: dyld4::Loader::setUpPageInLinking(Diagnostics&, dyld4::RuntimeState&, unsigned long, unsigned long long, dyld3::Array<void const*> const&) const (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==39646==    by 0x10002BFCA: dyld4::Loader::applyFixupsGeneric(Diagnostics&, dyld4::RuntimeState&, unsigned long long, dyld3::Array<void const*> const&, dyld3::Array<void const*> const&, bool, dyld3::Array<dyld4::Loader::MissingFlatLazySymbol> const&) const (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==39646==    by 0x100031268: dyld4::JustInTimeLoader::applyFixups(Diagnostics&, dyld4::RuntimeState&, dyld4::DyldCacheDataConstLazyScopedWriter&, bool) const (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==39646==    by 0x1000172A4: dyld4::prepare(dyld4::APIs&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer const*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==39646==    by 0x1000163BC: (below main) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==39646==  Address 0x10490c910 is on thread 1's stack
==39646==  in frame #1, created by dyld4::setUpPageInLinkingRegions(dyld4::RuntimeState&, dyld4::Loader const*, unsigned long, unsigned short, unsigned short, bool, dyld3::Array<dyld4::PageInLinkingRange> const&, dyld3::Array<void const*> const&) (???:)
==39646== 
==39646== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==39646==    at 0x7FF80B359120: ???
==39646==    by 0x7FF80B25BBBF: _init_clock_port (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==39646==    by 0x7FF80B25BAA3: _libc_initializer (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==39646==    by 0x7FF8171F7846: libSystem_initializer (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==39646==    by 0x10002F41A: invocation function for block in dyld4::Loader::findAndRunAllInitializers(dyld4::RuntimeState&) const::$_0::operator()() const (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==39646==    by 0x10006DB69: invocation function for block in dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::forEachInitializer(Diagnostics&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::VMAddrConverter const&, void ( block_pointer)(unsigned int), void const*) const (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==39646==    by 0x100061F21: invocation function for block in dyld3::MachOFile::forEachSection(void ( block_pointer)(dyld3::MachOFile::SectionInfo const&, bool, bool&)) const (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==39646==    by 0x1000120AE: dyld3::MachOFile::forEachLoadCommand(Diagnostics&, void ( block_pointer)(load_command const*, bool&)) const (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==39646==    by 0x1000610BE: dyld3::MachOFile::forEachSection(void ( block_pointer)(dyld3::MachOFile::SectionInfo const&, bool, bool&)) const (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==39646==    by 0x10006D729: dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::forEachInitializer(Diagnostics&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::VMAddrConverter const&, void ( block_pointer)(unsigned int), void const*) const (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==39646==    by 0x10002C68B: dyld4::Loader::findAndRunAllInitializers(dyld4::RuntimeState&) const (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==39646==    by 0x1000351F3: dyld4::PrebuiltLoader::runInitializers(dyld4::RuntimeState&) const (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==39646== 
==39646== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0xffffffff000, 0x120000000000) (defined)
==39646== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x140000000000, 0x200000000000) (defined)
==39646== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x120000000000, 0x140000000000) (noaccess)
==39646== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x600000000000, 0x640000002000) (noaccess)
GenerateParentheses_Task22-main(39646,0x1000b8280) malloc: nano zone abandoned due to inability to reserve vm space.
==39646== Syscall param socketcall.sendto(msg) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==39646==    at 0x7FF80B357C2E: ???
==39646==    by 0x1005078C6: wrap_dlclose (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/14.0.3/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==39646==    by 0x7FF80B3C1C35: ???
==39646==    by 0x7FF80B3C1AC6: ???
==39646==    by 0x7FF80B3C1D67: ???
==39646==    by 0x7FF80B1D05F8: malloc_vreport (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib)
==39646==    by 0x7FF80B1D3B30: malloc_report (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib)
==39646==    by 0x7FF80B1D2D2A: nanov2_create_zone (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib)
==39646==    by 0x7FF80B1D1C99: __malloc_init (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib)
==39646==    by 0x7FF8171F7859: libSystem_initializer (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==39646==    by 0x10002F41A: invocation function for block in dyld4::Loader::findAndRunAllInitializers(dyld4::RuntimeState&) const::$_0::operator()() const (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==39646==    by 0x10006DB69: invocation function for block in dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::forEachInitializer(Diagnostics&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer::VMAddrConverter const&, void ( block_pointer)(unsigned int), void const*) const (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==39646==  Address 0x10490c625 is on thread 1's stack
==39646== 
==39646== Invalid read of size 1
==39646==    at 0x1004D0A06: ??? (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/14.0.3/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==39646==    by 0x100514F4D: __wrap_dispatch_after_block_invoke (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/14.0.3/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==39646==    by 0x7FF80AFFBD87: _NXHashRehashToCapacity (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==39646==    by 0x7FF80AFFBCB1: NXHashInsert (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==39646==    by 0x7FF80AFFB97D: NXCreateHashTableFromZone (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==39646==    by 0x7FF80AFFB761: NXCreateMapTableFromZone (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==39646==    by 0x7FF80AFFA2DB: map_images_nolock (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==39646==    by 0x7FF80AFF960E: map_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==39646==    by 0x10002575F: invocation function for block in dyld4::RuntimeState::setObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(mach_header const*, void*, mach_header const*, void const*), void (*)(unsigned int, _dyld_objc_notify_mapped_info const*))::$_8::operator()() const (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==39646==    by 0x10001D6F8: dyld4::RuntimeState::withLoadersReadLock(void ( block_pointer)()) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==39646==    by 0x1000225FA: dyld4::RuntimeState::setObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(mach_header const*, void*, mach_header const*, void const*), void (*)(unsigned int, _dyld_objc_notify_mapped_info const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==39646==    by 0x100048187: dyld4::APIs::_dyld_objc_register_callbacks(_dyld_objc_callbacks const*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==39646==  Address 0x1027001a0 is 16 bytes before a block of size 24 alloc'd
==39646==    at 0x10017B856: malloc_zone_calloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD-8c360fc/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==39646==    by 0x7FF80AFFBC77: NXHashInsert (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==39646==    by 0x7FF80AFFB97D: NXCreateHashTableFromZone (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==39646==    by 0x7FF80AFFB761: NXCreateMapTableFromZone (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==39646==    by 0x7FF80AFFA2DB: map_images_nolock (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==39646==    by 0x7FF80AFF960E: map_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==39646==    by 0x10002575F: invocation function for block in dyld4::RuntimeState::setObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(mach_header const*, void*, mach_header const*, void const*), void (*)(unsigned int, _dyld_objc_notify_mapped_info const*))::$_8::operator()() const (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==39646==    by 0x10001D6F8: dyld4::RuntimeState::withLoadersReadLock(void ( block_pointer)()) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==39646==    by 0x1000225FA: dyld4::RuntimeState::setObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(mach_header const*, void*, mach_header const*, void const*), void (*)(unsigned int, _dyld_objc_notify_mapped_info const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==39646==    by 0x100048187: dyld4::APIs::_dyld_objc_register_callbacks(_dyld_objc_callbacks const*) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==39646==    by 0x7FF80AFF90CE: _objc_init (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==39646==    by 0x7FF80B1F16A8: _os_object_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==39646== 
=================================================================
==39646==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: attempting free on address which was not malloc()-ed: 0x0001027001b0 in thread T0
==39646== Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall close()
==39646==WARNING: Can't read from symbolizer at fd 5
==39646== Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall close()
==39646==WARNING: Can't read from symbolizer at fd 6
==39646== Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall close()
==39646==WARNING: Can't read from symbolizer at fd 7
==39646== Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall close()
==39646==WARNING: Can't read from symbolizer at fd 8
==39646== Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall close()
==39646==WARNING: Failed to use and restart external symbolizer!
    #0 0x100514ee9 in wrap_free+0xa9 (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/14.0.3/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64h+0x48ee9) (BuildId: 756bb7515781379f84412f22c4274ffd2400000010000000000a0a0000030d00)
    #1 0x7ff80affbd87 in _NXHashRehashToCapacity+0xc4 (/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x4d87) (BuildId: 4fc61ea7873735738d14f8f342b438aa32000000200000000100000000040d00)
    #2 0x7ff80affbcb1 in NXHashInsert+0x18a (/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x4cb1) (BuildId: 4fc61ea7873735738d14f8f342b438aa32000000200000000100000000040d00)
    #3 0x7ff80affb97d in NXCreateHashTableFromZone+0x115 (/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x497d) (BuildId: 4fc61ea7873735738d14f8f342b438aa32000000200000000100000000040d00)
    #4 0x7ff80affb761 in NXCreateMapTableFromZone+0x56 (/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x4761) (BuildId: 4fc61ea7873735738d14f8f342b438aa32000000200000000100000000040d00)
    #5 0x7ff80affa2db in map_images_nolock+0xc52 (/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x32db) (BuildId: 4fc61ea7873735738d14f8f342b438aa32000000200000000100000000040d00)
    #6 0x7ff80aff960e in map_images+0x42 (/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x260e) (BuildId: 4fc61ea7873735738d14f8f342b438aa32000000200000000100000000040d00)
    #7 0x10002575f  (<unknown module>)
    #8 0x10001d6f8  (<unknown module>)
    #9 0x1000225fa  (<unknown module>)
    #10 0x100048187  (<unknown module>)
    #11 0x7ff80aff90ce in _objc_init+0x24a (/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x20ce) (BuildId: 4fc61ea7873735738d14f8f342b438aa32000000200000000100000000040d00)
    #12 0x7ff80b1f16a8 in _os_object_init+0xc (/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib:x86_64+0x26a8) (BuildId: da7432300aca3094821c5e1565d8b18732000000200000000100000000040d00)
    #13 0x7ff80b1ff566 in libdispatch_init+0x16a (/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib:x86_64+0x10566) (BuildId: da7432300aca3094821c5e1565d8b18732000000200000000100000000040d00)
    #14 0x7ff8171f7897 in libSystem_initializer+0xed (/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib:x86_64+0x1897) (BuildId: 65c3ab0214233a369e9388bc046941d832000000200000000100000000040d00)
    #15 0x10002f41a  (<unknown module>)
    #16 0x10006db69  (<unknown module>)
    #17 0x100061f21  (<unknown module>)
    #18 0x1000120ae  (<unknown module>)
    #19 0x1000610be  (<unknown module>)
    #20 0x10006d729  (<unknown module>)
    #21 0x10002c68b  (<unknown module>)
    #22 0x1000351f3  (<unknown module>)
    #23 0x10004dbdc  (<unknown module>)
    #24 0x100017873  (<unknown module>)
    #25 0x1000163bc  (<unknown module>)

Address 0x0001027001b0 is a wild pointer inside of access range of size 0x000000000001.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: bad-free (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/14.0.3/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64h+0x48ee9) (BuildId: 756bb7515781379f84412f22c4274ffd2400000010000000000a0a0000030d00) in wrap_free+0xa9
==39646== Invalid read of size 4
==39646==    at 0x7FF80AFFE2E4: class_createInstance (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==39646==    by 0x7FF80B1F1746: _os_object_alloc_realized (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==39646==    by 0x7FF80B0D4D22: xpc_bundle_create_from_origin (in /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib)
==39646==    by 0x7FF80B0D861B: xpc_bundle_create_main (in /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib)
==39646==    by 0x7FF80B112CCC: _os_trace_init_slow (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib)
==39646==    by 0x7FF80B1F2032: _dispatch_client_callout (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==39646==    by 0x7FF80B1F3266: _dispatch_once_callout (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==39646==    by 0x7FF80B11F5B0: _os_trace_with_buffer (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib)
==39646==    by 0x100530D76: __sanitizer::GetRSS() (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/14.0.3/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==39646==    by 0x10051DC6F: __asan::ScopedInErrorReport::~ScopedInErrorReport() (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/14.0.3/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==39646==    by 0x10051A89E: __asan::ReportFreeNotMalloced(unsigned long, __sanitizer::BufferedStackTrace*) (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/14.0.3/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==39646==    by 0x100514F4D: __wrap_dispatch_after_block_invoke (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/14.0.3/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==39646==  Address 0x10 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==39646== 
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
AddressSanitizer: nested bug in the same thread, aborting.
==39646== 
==39646== HEAP SUMMARY:
==39646==     in use at exit: 208 bytes in 7 blocks
==39646==   total heap usage: 7 allocs, 0 frees, 208 bytes allocated
==39646== 
[1]    39646 killed     valgrind --leak-check=full ./GenerateParentheses_Task22-main
```

i am new to valgrind, so i search the the doc and list some of key points in the log:

1. "Syscall param map_with_linking_np(link_info) points to uninitialised byte(s)" may caused by the use of uninitialized memory, but all the allocated are created by calloc
2. "Using a pointer that points to a local variable that has gone out of scope" may caused by "using a pointer that points to a local var that has gone out of scope" or "useing a pointer to a stack-allocated buffer after the buffer has gone out of scope"
3. "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)" may caused by a conditional branch or move instruction in your program that depends on the value of an uninitialized variable

but i still not sure about what exactly the problem is. Can you help me figure it out? i really don't know what to do next. :(
Of course, @Whozcry's solution is surely better in these aspects:

1. it is a backtracking version to drop useless case to save time
2. it use a global variable of `char* stack` instead of allocating block in each level of recursion.

, but i just want to understand heap-buffer-overflow problem better because i have met this in a lot of scenes. I will take a backtracking version or dp version solution, but after this heap-buffer-overflow is located. :(

Comment: This `strcat(curStrNewLeft, curStr);` isn't going to work, because `curStrNewLeft` is not a nul-terminated string. It is uninitialised memory. Also, make sure there is room for the string terminator in the memory allocation. And, you don't `free` any of the allocations.

Comment: Thanks for your help, my problem is still not figured out. I updated the effort i have made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your program have too much `malloc` that no `free` , so it will result to memory leak.

Here is my answer, because [the link](https://leetcode.com/problems/generate-parentheses/)  `Constraints: 1 <= n <= 8` , so I test n = 8.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void dfs(int n, int left, int right, char *stack, int len, char** results, int *count)
{
    if (len == 2 * n) {
        results[*count] = malloc((len + 1) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(results[(*count)++], stack);
        return;
    }

    if (left < n) {
        stack[len] = '(';
        dfs(n, left + 1, right, stack, len + 1, results, count);
    }

    if (right < left) {
        stack[len] = ')';
        dfs(n, left, right + 1, stack, len + 1, results, count);
    }
}

/**
 ** Return an array of size *returnSize.
 ** Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().
 **/
char** generateParenthesis(int n, int* returnSize)
{
    char *stack = calloc(2 * n + 1, sizeof(char));
    char** parentheses = malloc(sizeof(char) * 80000);;
    *returnSize = 0;
    dfs(n, 0, 0, stack, 0, parentheses, returnSize);
    free(stack);
    return parentheses;
}

int main()
{
    
    int i, count;
    char ** lists = generateParenthesis(8, &count);
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", lists[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        free(lists[i]);
    }
    free(lists);
    return 0;
}
```

Run it will output:

```
(((((((())))))))
((((((()()))))))
((((((())())))))
((((((()))()))))
((((((())))())))
((((((()))))()))
((((((())))))())
((((((()))))))()
(((((()(()))))))
(((((()()())))))
(((((()())()))))
(((((()()))())))
(((((()())))()))
(((((()()))))())
(((((()())))))()
(((((())(())))))
(((((())()()))))
(((((())())())))
(((((())()))()))
(((((())())))())
(((((())()))))()
(((((()))(()))))
(((((()))()())))
(((((()))())()))
(((((()))()))())
(((((()))())))()
(((((())))(())))
(((((())))()()))
(((((())))())())
(((((())))()))()
(((((()))))(()))
(((((()))))()())
(((((()))))())()
(((((())))))(())
(((((())))))()()
((((()((()))))))
((((()(()())))))
((((()(())()))))
((((()(()))())))
((((()(())))()))
((((()(()))))())
((((()(())))))()
((((()()(())))))
((((()()()()))))
((((()()())())))
((((()()()))()))
((((()()())))())
((((()()()))))()
((((()())(()))))
((((()())()())))
((((()())())()))
((((()())()))())
((((()())())))()
((((()()))(())))
((((()()))()()))
((((()()))())())
((((()()))()))()
((((()())))(()))
((((()())))()())
((((()())))())()
((((()()))))(())
((((()()))))()()
((((())((())))))
((((())(()()))))
((((())(())())))
((((())(()))()))
((((())(())))())
((((())(()))))()
((((())()(()))))
((((())()()())))
((((())()())()))
((((())()()))())
((((())()())))()
((((())())(())))
((((())())()()))
((((())())())())
((((())())()))()
((((())()))(()))
((((())()))()())
((((())()))())()
((((())())))(())
((((())())))()()
((((()))((()))))
((((()))(()())))
((((()))(())()))
((((()))(()))())
((((()))(())))()
((((()))()(())))
((((()))()()()))
((((()))()())())
((((()))()()))()
((((()))())(()))
((((()))())()())
((((()))())())()
((((()))()))(())
((((()))()))()()
((((())))((())))
((((())))(()()))
((((())))(())())
((((())))(()))()
((((())))()(()))
((((())))()()())
((((())))()())()
((((())))())(())
((((())))())()()
((((()))))((()))
((((()))))(()())
((((()))))(())()
((((()))))()(())
((((()))))()()()
(((()(((()))))))
(((()((()())))))
(((()((())()))))
(((()((()))())))
(((()((())))()))
(((()((()))))())
(((()((())))))()
(((()(()(())))))
(((()(()()()))))
(((()(()())())))
(((()(()()))()))
(((()(()())))())
(((()(()()))))()
(((()(())(()))))
(((()(())()())))
(((()(())())()))
(((()(())()))())
(((()(())())))()
(((()(()))(())))
(((()(()))()()))
(((()(()))())())
(((()(()))()))()
(((()(())))(()))
(((()(())))()())
(((()(())))())()
(((()(()))))(())
(((()(()))))()()
(((()()((())))))
(((()()(()()))))
(((()()(())())))
(((()()(()))()))
(((()()(())))())
(((()()(()))))()
(((()()()(()))))
(((()()()()())))
(((()()()())()))
(((()()()()))())
(((()()()())))()
(((()()())(())))
(((()()())()()))
(((()()())())())
(((()()())()))()
(((()()()))(()))
(((()()()))()())
(((()()()))())()
(((()()())))(())
(((()()())))()()
(((()())((()))))
(((()())(()())))
(((()())(())()))
(((()())(()))())
(((()())(())))()
(((()())()(())))
(((()())()()()))
(((()())()())())
(((()())()()))()
(((()())())(()))
(((()())())()())
(((()())())())()
(((()())()))(())
(((()())()))()()
(((()()))((())))
(((()()))(()()))
(((()()))(())())
(((()()))(()))()
(((()()))()(()))
(((()()))()()())
(((()()))()())()
(((()()))())(())
(((()()))())()()
(((()())))((()))
(((()())))(()())
(((()())))(())()
(((()())))()(())
(((()())))()()()
(((())(((())))))
(((())((()()))))
(((())((())())))
(((())((()))()))
(((())((())))())
(((())((()))))()
(((())(()(()))))
(((())(()()())))
(((())(()())()))
(((())(()()))())
(((())(()())))()
(((())(())(())))
(((())(())()()))
(((())(())())())
(((())(())()))()
(((())(()))(()))
(((())(()))()())
(((())(()))())()
(((())(())))(())
(((())(())))()()
(((())()((()))))
(((())()(()())))
(((())()(())()))
(((())()(()))())
(((())()(())))()
(((())()()(())))
(((())()()()()))
(((())()()())())
(((())()()()))()
(((())()())(()))
(((())()())()())
(((())()())())()
(((())()()))(())
(((())()()))()()
(((())())((())))
(((())())(()()))
(((())())(())())
(((())())(()))()
(((())())()(()))
(((())())()()())
(((())())()())()
(((())())())(())
(((())())())()()
(((())()))((()))
(((())()))(()())
(((())()))(())()
(((())()))()(())
(((())()))()()()
(((()))(((()))))
(((()))((()())))
(((()))((())()))
(((()))((()))())
(((()))((())))()
(((()))(()(())))
(((()))(()()()))
(((()))(()())())
(((()))(()()))()
(((()))(())(()))
(((()))(())()())
(((()))(())())()
(((()))(()))(())
(((()))(()))()()
(((()))()((())))
(((()))()(()()))
(((()))()(())())
(((()))()(()))()
(((()))()()(()))
(((()))()()()())
(((()))()()())()
(((()))()())(())
(((()))()())()()
(((()))())((()))
(((()))())(()())
(((()))())(())()
(((()))())()(())
(((()))())()()()
(((())))(((())))
(((())))((()()))
(((())))((())())
(((())))((()))()
(((())))(()(()))
(((())))(()()())
(((())))(()())()
(((())))(())(())
(((())))(())()()
(((())))()((()))
(((())))()(()())
(((())))()(())()
(((())))()()(())
(((())))()()()()
((()((((()))))))
((()(((()())))))
((()(((())()))))
((()(((()))())))
((()(((())))()))
((()(((()))))())
((()(((())))))()
((()((()(())))))
((()((()()()))))
((()((()())())))
((()((()()))()))
((()((()())))())
((()((()()))))()
((()((())(()))))
((()((())()())))
((()((())())()))
((()((())()))())
((()((())())))()
((()((()))(())))
((()((()))()()))
((()((()))())())
((()((()))()))()
((()((())))(()))
((()((())))()())
((()((())))())()
((()((()))))(())
((()((()))))()()
((()(()((())))))
((()(()(()()))))
((()(()(())())))
((()(()(()))()))
((()(()(())))())
((()(()(()))))()
((()(()()(()))))
((()(()()()())))
((()(()()())()))
((()(()()()))())
((()(()()())))()
((()(()())(())))
((()(()())()()))
((()(()())())())
((()(()())()))()
((()(()()))(()))
((()(()()))()())
((()(()()))())()
((()(()())))(())
((()(()())))()()
((()(())((()))))
((()(())(()())))
((()(())(())()))
((()(())(()))())
((()(())(())))()
((()(())()(())))
((()(())()()()))
((()(())()())())
((()(())()()))()
((()(())())(()))
((()(())())()())
((()(())())())()
((()(())()))(())
((()(())()))()()
((()(()))((())))
((()(()))(()()))
((()(()))(())())
((()(()))(()))()
((()(()))()(()))
((()(()))()()())
((()(()))()())()
((()(()))())(())
((()(()))())()()
((()(())))((()))
((()(())))(()())
((()(())))(())()
((()(())))()(())
((()(())))()()()
((()()(((())))))
((()()((()()))))
((()()((())())))
((()()((()))()))
((()()((())))())
((()()((()))))()
((()()(()(()))))
((()()(()()())))
((()()(()())()))
((()()(()()))())
((()()(()())))()
((()()(())(())))
((()()(())()()))
((()()(())())())
((()()(())()))()
((()()(()))(()))
((()()(()))()())
((()()(()))())()
((()()(())))(())
((()()(())))()()
((()()()((()))))
((()()()(()())))
((()()()(())()))
((()()()(()))())
((()()()(())))()
((()()()()(())))
((()()()()()()))
((()()()()())())
((()()()()()))()
((()()()())(()))
((()()()())()())
((()()()())())()
((()()()()))(())
((()()()()))()()
((()()())((())))
((()()())(()()))
((()()())(())())
((()()())(()))()
((()()())()(()))
((()()())()()())
((()()())()())()
((()()())())(())
((()()())())()()
((()()()))((()))
((()()()))(()())
((()()()))(())()
((()()()))()(())
((()()()))()()()
((()())(((()))))
((()())((()())))
((()())((())()))
((()())((()))())
((()())((())))()
((()())(()(())))
((()())(()()()))
((()())(()())())
((()())(()()))()
((()())(())(()))
((()())(())()())
((()())(())())()
((()())(()))(())
((()())(()))()()
((()())()((())))
((()())()(()()))
((()())()(())())
((()())()(()))()
((()())()()(()))
((()())()()()())
((()())()()())()
((()())()())(())
((()())()())()()
((()())())((()))
((()())())(()())
((()())())(())()
((()())())()(())
((()())())()()()
((()()))(((())))
((()()))((()()))
((()()))((())())
((()()))((()))()
((()()))(()(()))
((()()))(()()())
((()()))(()())()
((()()))(())(())
((()()))(())()()
((()()))()((()))
((()()))()(()())
((()()))()(())()
((()()))()()(())
((()()))()()()()
((())((((())))))
((())(((()()))))
((())(((())())))
((())(((()))()))
((())(((())))())
((())(((()))))()
((())((()(()))))
((())((()()())))
((())((()())()))
((())((()()))())
((())((()())))()
((())((())(())))
((())((())()()))
((())((())())())
((())((())()))()
((())((()))(()))
((())((()))()())
((())((()))())()
((())((())))(())
((())((())))()()
((())(()((()))))
((())(()(()())))
((())(()(())()))
((())(()(()))())
((())(()(())))()
((())(()()(())))
((())(()()()()))
((())(()()())())
((())(()()()))()
((())(()())(()))
((())(()())()())
((())(()())())()
((())(()()))(())
((())(()()))()()
((())(())((())))
((())(())(()()))
((())(())(())())
((())(())(()))()
((())(())()(()))
((())(())()()())
((())(())()())()
((())(())())(())
((())(())())()()
((())(()))((()))
((())(()))(()())
((())(()))(())()
((())(()))()(())
((())(()))()()()
((())()(((()))))
((())()((()())))
((())()((())()))
((())()((()))())
((())()((())))()
((())()(()(())))
((())()(()()()))
((())()(()())())
((())()(()()))()
((())()(())(()))
((())()(())()())
((())()(())())()
((())()(()))(())
((())()(()))()()
((())()()((())))
((())()()(()()))
((())()()(())())
((())()()(()))()
((())()()()(()))
((())()()()()())
((())()()()())()
((())()()())(())
((())()()())()()
((())()())((()))
((())()())(()())
((())()())(())()
((())()())()(())
((())()())()()()
((())())(((())))
((())())((()()))
((())())((())())
((())())((()))()
((())())(()(()))
((())())(()()())
((())())(()())()
((())())(())(())
((())())(())()()
((())())()((()))
((())())()(()())
((())())()(())()
((())())()()(())
((())())()()()()
((()))((((()))))
((()))(((()())))
((()))(((())()))
((()))(((()))())
((()))(((())))()
((()))((()(())))
((()))((()()()))
((()))((()())())
((()))((()()))()
((()))((())(()))
((()))((())()())
((()))((())())()
((()))((()))(())
((()))((()))()()
((()))(()((())))
((()))(()(()()))
((()))(()(())())
((()))(()(()))()
((()))(()()(()))
((()))(()()()())
((()))(()()())()
((()))(()())(())
((()))(()())()()
((()))(())((()))
((()))(())(()())
((()))(())(())()
((()))(())()(())
((()))(())()()()
((()))()(((())))
((()))()((()()))
((()))()((())())
((()))()((()))()
((()))()(()(()))
((()))()(()()())
((()))()(()())()
((()))()(())(())
((()))()(())()()
((()))()()((()))
((()))()()(()())
((()))()()(())()
((()))()()()(())
((()))()()()()()
(()(((((()))))))
(()((((()())))))
(()((((())()))))
(()((((()))())))
(()((((())))()))
(()((((()))))())
(()((((())))))()
(()(((()(())))))
(()(((()()()))))
(()(((()())())))
(()(((()()))()))
(()(((()())))())
(()(((()()))))()
(()(((())(()))))
(()(((())()())))
(()(((())())()))
(()(((())()))())
(()(((())())))()
(()(((()))(())))
(()(((()))()()))
(()(((()))())())
(()(((()))()))()
(()(((())))(()))
(()(((())))()())
(()(((())))())()
(()(((()))))(())
(()(((()))))()()
(()((()((())))))
(()((()(()()))))
(()((()(())())))
(()((()(()))()))
(()((()(())))())
(()((()(()))))()
(()((()()(()))))
(()((()()()())))
(()((()()())()))
(()((()()()))())
(()((()()())))()
(()((()())(())))
(()((()())()()))
(()((()())())())
(()((()())()))()
(()((()()))(()))
(()((()()))()())
(()((()()))())()
(()((()())))(())
(()((()())))()()
(()((())((()))))
(()((())(()())))
(()((())(())()))
(()((())(()))())
(()((())(())))()
(()((())()(())))
(()((())()()()))
(()((())()())())
(()((())()()))()
(()((())())(()))
(()((())())()())
(()((())())())()
(()((())()))(())
(()((())()))()()
(()((()))((())))
(()((()))(()()))
(()((()))(())())
(()((()))(()))()
(()((()))()(()))
(()((()))()()())
(()((()))()())()
(()((()))())(())
(()((()))())()()
(()((())))((()))
(()((())))(()())
(()((())))(())()
(()((())))()(())
(()((())))()()()
(()(()(((())))))
(()(()((()()))))
(()(()((())())))
(()(()((()))()))
(()(()((())))())
(()(()((()))))()
(()(()(()(()))))
(()(()(()()())))
(()(()(()())()))
(()(()(()()))())
(()(()(()())))()
(()(()(())(())))
(()(()(())()()))
(()(()(())())())
(()(()(())()))()
(()(()(()))(()))
(()(()(()))()())
(()(()(()))())()
(()(()(())))(())
(()(()(())))()()
(()(()()((()))))
(()(()()(()())))
(()(()()(())()))
(()(()()(()))())
(()(()()(())))()
(()(()()()(())))
(()(()()()()()))
(()(()()()())())
(()(()()()()))()
(()(()()())(()))
(()(()()())()())
(()(()()())())()
(()(()()()))(())
(()(()()()))()()
(()(()())((())))
(()(()())(()()))
(()(()())(())())
(()(()())(()))()
(()(()())()(()))
(()(()())()()())
(()(()())()())()
(()(()())())(())
(()(()())())()()
(()(()()))((()))
(()(()()))(()())
(()(()()))(())()
(()(()()))()(())
(()(()()))()()()
(()(())(((()))))
(()(())((()())))
(()(())((())()))
(()(())((()))())
(()(())((())))()
(()(())(()(())))
(()(())(()()()))
(()(())(()())())
(()(())(()()))()
(()(())(())(()))
(()(())(())()())
(()(())(())())()
(()(())(()))(())
(()(())(()))()()
(()(())()((())))
(()(())()(()()))
(()(())()(())())
(()(())()(()))()
(()(())()()(()))
(()(())()()()())
(()(())()()())()
(()(())()())(())
(()(())()())()()
(()(())())((()))
(()(())())(()())
(()(())())(())()
(()(())())()(())
(()(())())()()()
(()(()))(((())))
(()(()))((()()))
(()(()))((())())
(()(()))((()))()
(()(()))(()(()))
(()(()))(()()())
(()(()))(()())()
(()(()))(())(())
(()(()))(())()()
(()(()))()((()))
(()(()))()(()())
(()(()))()(())()
(()(()))()()(())
(()(()))()()()()
(()()((((())))))
(()()(((()()))))
(()()(((())())))
(()()(((()))()))
(()()(((())))())
(()()(((()))))()
(()()((()(()))))
(()()((()()())))
(()()((()())()))
(()()((()()))())
(()()((()())))()
(()()((())(())))
(()()((())()()))
(()()((())())())
(()()((())()))()
(()()((()))(()))
(()()((()))()())
(()()((()))())()
(()()((())))(())
(()()((())))()()
(()()(()((()))))
(()()(()(()())))
(()()(()(())()))
(()()(()(()))())
(()()(()(())))()
(()()(()()(())))
(()()(()()()()))
(()()(()()())())
(()()(()()()))()
(()()(()())(()))
(()()(()())()())
(()()(()())())()
(()()(()()))(())
(()()(()()))()()
(()()(())((())))
(()()(())(()()))
(()()(())(())())
(()()(())(()))()
(()()(())()(()))
(()()(())()()())
(()()(())()())()
(()()(())())(())
(()()(())())()()
(()()(()))((()))
(()()(()))(()())
(()()(()))(())()
(()()(()))()(())
(()()(()))()()()
(()()()(((()))))
(()()()((()())))
(()()()((())()))
(()()()((()))())
(()()()((())))()
(()()()(()(())))
(()()()(()()()))
(()()()(()())())
(()()()(()()))()
(()()()(())(()))
(()()()(())()())
(()()()(())())()
(()()()(()))(())
(()()()(()))()()
(()()()()((())))
(()()()()(()()))
(()()()()(())())
(()()()()(()))()
(()()()()()(()))
(()()()()()()())
(()()()()()())()
(()()()()())(())
(()()()()())()()
(()()()())((()))
(()()()())(()())
(()()()())(())()
(()()()())()(())
(()()()())()()()
(()()())(((())))
(()()())((()()))
(()()())((())())
(()()())((()))()
(()()())(()(()))
(()()())(()()())
(()()())(()())()
(()()())(())(())
(()()())(())()()
(()()())()((()))
(()()())()(()())
(()()())()(())()
(()()())()()(())
(()()())()()()()
(()())((((()))))
(()())(((()())))
(()())(((())()))
(()())(((()))())
(()())(((())))()
(()())((()(())))
(()())((()()()))
(()())((()())())
(()())((()()))()
(()())((())(()))
(()())((())()())
(()())((())())()
(()())((()))(())
(()())((()))()()
(()())(()((())))
(()())(()(()()))
(()())(()(())())
(()())(()(()))()
(()())(()()(()))
(()())(()()()())
(()())(()()())()
(()())(()())(())
(()())(()())()()
(()())(())((()))
(()())(())(()())
(()())(())(())()
(()())(())()(())
(()())(())()()()
(()())()(((())))
(()())()((()()))
(()())()((())())
(()())()((()))()
(()())()(()(()))
(()())()(()()())
(()())()(()())()
(()())()(())(())
(()())()(())()()
(()())()()((()))
(()())()()(()())
(()())()()(())()
(()())()()()(())
(()())()()()()()
(())(((((())))))
(())((((()()))))
(())((((())())))
(())((((()))()))
(())((((())))())
(())((((()))))()
(())(((()(()))))
(())(((()()())))
(())(((()())()))
(())(((()()))())
(())(((()())))()
(())(((())(())))
(())(((())()()))
(())(((())())())
(())(((())()))()
(())(((()))(()))
(())(((()))()())
(())(((()))())()
(())(((())))(())
(())(((())))()()
(())((()((()))))
(())((()(()())))
(())((()(())()))
(())((()(()))())
(())((()(())))()
(())((()()(())))
(())((()()()()))
(())((()()())())
(())((()()()))()
(())((()())(()))
(())((()())()())
(())((()())())()
(())((()()))(())
(())((()()))()()
(())((())((())))
(())((())(()()))
(())((())(())())
(())((())(()))()
(())((())()(()))
(())((())()()())
(())((())()())()
(())((())())(())
(())((())())()()
(())((()))((()))
(())((()))(()())
(())((()))(())()
(())((()))()(())
(())((()))()()()
(())(()(((()))))
(())(()((()())))
(())(()((())()))
(())(()((()))())
(())(()((())))()
(())(()(()(())))
(())(()(()()()))
(())(()(()())())
(())(()(()()))()
(())(()(())(()))
(())(()(())()())
(())(()(())())()
(())(()(()))(())
(())(()(()))()()
(())(()()((())))
(())(()()(()()))
(())(()()(())())
(())(()()(()))()
(())(()()()(()))
(())(()()()()())
(())(()()()())()
(())(()()())(())
(())(()()())()()
(())(()())((()))
(())(()())(()())
(())(()())(())()
(())(()())()(())
(())(()())()()()
(())(())(((())))
(())(())((()()))
(())(())((())())
(())(())((()))()
(())(())(()(()))
(())(())(()()())
(())(())(()())()
(())(())(())(())
(())(())(())()()
(())(())()((()))
(())(())()(()())
(())(())()(())()
(())(())()()(())
(())(())()()()()
(())()((((()))))
(())()(((()())))
(())()(((())()))
(())()(((()))())
(())()(((())))()
(())()((()(())))
(())()((()()()))
(())()((()())())
(())()((()()))()
(())()((())(()))
(())()((())()())
(())()((())())()
(())()((()))(())
(())()((()))()()
(())()(()((())))
(())()(()(()()))
(())()(()(())())
(())()(()(()))()
(())()(()()(()))
(())()(()()()())
(())()(()()())()
(())()(()())(())
(())()(()())()()
(())()(())((()))
(())()(())(()())
(())()(())(())()
(())()(())()(())
(())()(())()()()
(())()()(((())))
(())()()((()()))
(())()()((())())
(())()()((()))()
(())()()(()(()))
(())()()(()()())
(())()()(()())()
(())()()(())(())
(())()()(())()()
(())()()()((()))
(())()()()(()())
(())()()()(())()
(())()()()()(())
(())()()()()()()
()((((((()))))))
()(((((()())))))
()(((((())()))))
()(((((()))())))
()(((((())))()))
()(((((()))))())
()(((((())))))()
()((((()(())))))
()((((()()()))))
()((((()())())))
()((((()()))()))
()((((()())))())
()((((()()))))()
()((((())(()))))
()((((())()())))
()((((())())()))
()((((())()))())
()((((())())))()
()((((()))(())))
()((((()))()()))
()((((()))())())
()((((()))()))()
()((((())))(()))
()((((())))()())
()((((())))())()
()((((()))))(())
()((((()))))()()
()(((()((())))))
()(((()(()()))))
()(((()(())())))
()(((()(()))()))
()(((()(())))())
()(((()(()))))()
()(((()()(()))))
()(((()()()())))
()(((()()())()))
()(((()()()))())
()(((()()())))()
()(((()())(())))
()(((()())()()))
()(((()())())())
()(((()())()))()
()(((()()))(()))
()(((()()))()())
()(((()()))())()
()(((()())))(())
()(((()())))()()
()(((())((()))))
()(((())(()())))
()(((())(())()))
()(((())(()))())
()(((())(())))()
()(((())()(())))
()(((())()()()))
()(((())()())())
()(((())()()))()
()(((())())(()))
()(((())())()())
()(((())())())()
()(((())()))(())
()(((())()))()()
()(((()))((())))
()(((()))(()()))
()(((()))(())())
()(((()))(()))()
()(((()))()(()))
()(((()))()()())
()(((()))()())()
()(((()))())(())
()(((()))())()()
()(((())))((()))
()(((())))(()())
()(((())))(())()
()(((())))()(())
()(((())))()()()
()((()(((())))))
()((()((()()))))
()((()((())())))
()((()((()))()))
()((()((())))())
()((()((()))))()
()((()(()(()))))
()((()(()()())))
()((()(()())()))
()((()(()()))())
()((()(()())))()
()((()(())(())))
()((()(())()()))
()((()(())())())
()((()(())()))()
()((()(()))(()))
()((()(()))()())
()((()(()))())()
()((()(())))(())
()((()(())))()()
()((()()((()))))
()((()()(()())))
()((()()(())()))
()((()()(()))())
()((()()(())))()
()((()()()(())))
()((()()()()()))
()((()()()())())
()((()()()()))()
()((()()())(()))
()((()()())()())
()((()()())())()
()((()()()))(())
()((()()()))()()
()((()())((())))
()((()())(()()))
()((()())(())())
()((()())(()))()
()((()())()(()))
()((()())()()())
()((()())()())()
()((()())())(())
()((()())())()()
()((()()))((()))
()((()()))(()())
()((()()))(())()
()((()()))()(())
()((()()))()()()
()((())(((()))))
()((())((()())))
()((())((())()))
()((())((()))())
()((())((())))()
()((())(()(())))
()((())(()()()))
()((())(()())())
()((())(()()))()
()((())(())(()))
()((())(())()())
()((())(())())()
()((())(()))(())
()((())(()))()()
()((())()((())))
()((())()(()()))
()((())()(())())
()((())()(()))()
()((())()()(()))
()((())()()()())
()((())()()())()
()((())()())(())
()((())()())()()
()((())())((()))
()((())())(()())
()((())())(())()
()((())())()(())
()((())())()()()
()((()))(((())))
()((()))((()()))
()((()))((())())
()((()))((()))()
()((()))(()(()))
()((()))(()()())
()((()))(()())()
()((()))(())(())
()((()))(())()()
()((()))()((()))
()((()))()(()())
()((()))()(())()
()((()))()()(())
()((()))()()()()
()(()((((())))))
()(()(((()()))))
()(()(((())())))
()(()(((()))()))
()(()(((())))())
()(()(((()))))()
()(()((()(()))))
()(()((()()())))
()(()((()())()))
()(()((()()))())
()(()((()())))()
()(()((())(())))
()(()((())()()))
()(()((())())())
()(()((())()))()
()(()((()))(()))
()(()((()))()())
()(()((()))())()
()(()((())))(())
()(()((())))()()
()(()(()((()))))
()(()(()(()())))
()(()(()(())()))
()(()(()(()))())
()(()(()(())))()
()(()(()()(())))
()(()(()()()()))
()(()(()()())())
()(()(()()()))()
()(()(()())(()))
()(()(()())()())
()(()(()())())()
()(()(()()))(())
()(()(()()))()()
()(()(())((())))
()(()(())(()()))
()(()(())(())())
()(()(())(()))()
()(()(())()(()))
()(()(())()()())
()(()(())()())()
()(()(())())(())
()(()(())())()()
()(()(()))((()))
()(()(()))(()())
()(()(()))(())()
()(()(()))()(())
()(()(()))()()()
()(()()(((()))))
()(()()((()())))
()(()()((())()))
()(()()((()))())
()(()()((())))()
()(()()(()(())))
()(()()(()()()))
()(()()(()())())
()(()()(()()))()
()(()()(())(()))
()(()()(())()())
()(()()(())())()
()(()()(()))(())
()(()()(()))()()
()(()()()((())))
()(()()()(()()))
()(()()()(())())
()(()()()(()))()
()(()()()()(()))
()(()()()()()())
()(()()()()())()
()(()()()())(())
()(()()()())()()
()(()()())((()))
()(()()())(()())
()(()()())(())()
()(()()())()(())
()(()()())()()()
()(()())(((())))
()(()())((()()))
()(()())((())())
()(()())((()))()
()(()())(()(()))
()(()())(()()())
()(()())(()())()
()(()())(())(())
()(()())(())()()
()(()())()((()))
()(()())()(()())
()(()())()(())()
()(()())()()(())
()(()())()()()()
()(())((((()))))
()(())(((()())))
()(())(((())()))
()(())(((()))())
()(())(((())))()
()(())((()(())))
()(())((()()()))
()(())((()())())
()(())((()()))()
()(())((())(()))
()(())((())()())
()(())((())())()
()(())((()))(())
()(())((()))()()
()(())(()((())))
()(())(()(()()))
()(())(()(())())
()(())(()(()))()
()(())(()()(()))
()(())(()()()())
()(())(()()())()
()(())(()())(())
()(())(()())()()
()(())(())((()))
()(())(())(()())
()(())(())(())()
()(())(())()(())
()(())(())()()()
()(())()(((())))
()(())()((()()))
()(())()((())())
()(())()((()))()
()(())()(()(()))
()(())()(()()())
()(())()(()())()
()(())()(())(())
()(())()(())()()
()(())()()((()))
()(())()()(()())
()(())()()(())()
()(())()()()(())
()(())()()()()()
()()(((((())))))
()()((((()()))))
()()((((())())))
()()((((()))()))
()()((((())))())
()()((((()))))()
()()(((()(()))))
()()(((()()())))
()()(((()())()))
()()(((()()))())
()()(((()())))()
()()(((())(())))
()()(((())()()))
()()(((())())())
()()(((())()))()
()()(((()))(()))
()()(((()))()())
()()(((()))())()
()()(((())))(())
()()(((())))()()
()()((()((()))))
()()((()(()())))
()()((()(())()))
()()((()(()))())
()()((()(())))()
()()((()()(())))
()()((()()()()))
()()((()()())())
()()((()()()))()
()()((()())(()))
()()((()())()())
()()((()())())()
()()((()()))(())
()()((()()))()()
()()((())((())))
()()((())(()()))
()()((())(())())
()()((())(()))()
()()((())()(()))
()()((())()()())
()()((())()())()
()()((())())(())
()()((())())()()
()()((()))((()))
()()((()))(()())
()()((()))(())()
()()((()))()(())
()()((()))()()()
()()(()(((()))))
()()(()((()())))
()()(()((())()))
()()(()((()))())
()()(()((())))()
()()(()(()(())))
()()(()(()()()))
()()(()(()())())
()()(()(()()))()
()()(()(())(()))
()()(()(())()())
()()(()(())())()
()()(()(()))(())
()()(()(()))()()
()()(()()((())))
()()(()()(()()))
()()(()()(())())
()()(()()(()))()
()()(()()()(()))
()()(()()()()())
()()(()()()())()
()()(()()())(())
()()(()()())()()
()()(()())((()))
()()(()())(()())
()()(()())(())()
()()(()())()(())
()()(()())()()()
()()(())(((())))
()()(())((()()))
()()(())((())())
()()(())((()))()
()()(())(()(()))
()()(())(()()())
()()(())(()())()
()()(())(())(())
()()(())(())()()
()()(())()((()))
()()(())()(()())
()()(())()(())()
()()(())()()(())
()()(())()()()()
()()()((((()))))
()()()(((()())))
()()()(((())()))
()()()(((()))())
()()()(((())))()
()()()((()(())))
()()()((()()()))
()()()((()())())
()()()((()()))()
()()()((())(()))
()()()((())()())
()()()((())())()
()()()((()))(())
()()()((()))()()
()()()(()((())))
()()()(()(()()))
()()()(()(())())
()()()(()(()))()
()()()(()()(()))
()()()(()()()())
()()()(()()())()
()()()(()())(())
()()()(()())()()
()()()(())((()))
()()()(())(()())
()()()(())(())()
()()()(())()(())
()()()(())()()()
()()()()(((())))
()()()()((()()))
()()()()((())())
()()()()((()))()
()()()()(()(()))
()()()()(()()())
()()()()(()())()
()()()()(())(())
()()()()(())()()
()()()()()((()))
()()()()()(()())
()()()()()(())()
()()()()()()(())
()()()()()()()()
```

To debug to locate heap-buffer-overflow more efficiently, please see my answer about Valgrind use problem at  [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76523734/incorrect-joint-work-of-valgrind-with-gdb/76524099#76524099).

### Update

When you use command:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full ./GenerateParentheses_Task22-main
```

the last section of output:

```
==39646== HEAP SUMMARY:
==39646==     in use at exit: 208 bytes in 7 blocks
==39646==   total heap usage: 7 allocs, 0 frees, 208 bytes allocated
==39646== 
[1]    39646 killed     valgrind --leak-check=full ./GenerateParentheses_Task22-main
```

show

```
total heap usage: 7 allocs, 0 frees, 208 bytes allocated
```

you only allocates memory (**7 allocs**) but no `free` (**0 frees**).

so in your updated code may have no `free` error is:

```
res[(*returnSize)] = (char *) calloc(curStrLen + 1, sizeof(char));
char* curStrNewLeft = (char *) calloc(curStrLen + 2, sizeof(char));
char* curStrNewRight = (char *) calloc(curStrLen + 2, sizeof(char));
```

and

```
    if (curStrLen > 0) {
        free(curStr);
    }
```

may be is error.

I think there are many issues with the code you updated. If possible, I suggest using my code instead.

Comment: Really appreciating your detailed reply, i have tried several ways to solve it, but the problem still exists. I use valgrind to debug mem problem, i didn't see the exact line of my code leading to heap-buffer-overflow.

Comment: @khamun7  Your code seems that can't solve leetcode task 22, try to use my posted code.

Comment: your solution is better, but i want to understand this problem more, can you give me some suggestion. Does it related to the curStrNewRight in each level of "generateParenthesisRecursive(curStrNewLeft, curStrLen + 1, n, returnSize, res);" ?

Comment: @khamun7 Yes, please wait a moment for see my updated answer.

Comment: i figured it out, it is because there are too much recursion levels, but the updated code is nothing wrong, i test "n=3", it runs normally and the binary file also works. But when i test "n=8", the heap is overflow. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @khamun7 It sounds good, but I see leetcode task 22 `Constraints: 1 <= n <= 8`, it seems that your code can't accepted in n = 8 at leetcode website.

Answer (score 0):

`malloc` returns a pointer to uninitialized memory. When you `strcat` to this newly allocated block in the iterative case, it can overflow because it might be all 1's and only the last character is a nul-terminator.

To fix this, either use `calloc`, assign `\0` to the first character, or use `strcpy`

Comment: Thanks for your help, my problem is still not figured out, can you take a look at my updated question ?